# How to use command line arguments in a shell script

Tags: shell-script, arguments

I have a shell script and when invoking it `./test` it asks for an input.I 've seen a quicker way just by writing at once `./test myInput` ,how is that achievable?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can access the command line arguments in your shell script with the special variables `$1`, `$2` until `$9`. `$0` is the name of your script.

If you need access more than 9 command line arguments, you can use the `shift` command. Example: `shift 2` renames `$3` to `$1`, `$4` to `$2` etc.

Please remember to put the arguments inside doubles quotes (e.g. `"$1"`), otherwise you can get problems if they contain whitespaces.

Comment: You can use "double-digit" parameters directly, just use braces: `echo ${12}`

Comment: Also, `$#` gives you the number of arguments. For example, with `./test.sh a b c`, `$#` would evaluate to 3.

Comment: @glennjackman – should I be using the quotes around the parameter as in `echo "${12}"` or is the syntax sufficient as `echo ${12}`. What is the difference?

Comment: Using double quotes will prevent the shell from performing [word splitting](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Word-Splitting) and [filename expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Filename-Expansion). Use of braces allows you to use double-digit positional parameters, and to disambiguate variable names from surrounding text.

Comment: Demo: `set -- one two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven "12 twelve"; printf "%s\n" "${12}"; printf "%s\n" ${12}`